# Creating points on either side of the line at specified intervals

Tags: arcgis-desktop, create, point

[image]

With the tool "Generate points along line", it creates points along the line which I don't want.

I Want the distance between two alternating points (zig zag) should be 250m and between the distance from point to line should be 50m.

Comment: Do you want them perpendicular to the line?  From your image the first set of points aren't equidistant from the centreline. What do you mean by "Alternating Points", do you want the points to "zig-zag" at alternating positions perpendicular and 50m from the line?

Comment: I Want the positions of the points in a zig zag manner without intersecting lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to to this would be to use "Station Lines"

First: Download ET Geowizards from [www.ian-ko.com](http://www.ian-ko.com).
ET is a good toolset to have anyways for ArcMap.

Here are the steps I followed to get this result:
[image]

In the image above, the points are all 50m perpendicular to the centreline.
The points are 250m apart from each other (left side is 125m apart from the right side.).

To accomplish this I did the following:

1. Using ET GeoWizards I created two sets of Station Lines. The Station
   Lines tool is located within the "Miscellaneous -> Create Station
   Lines" Menu. The first station line set I names Lines_Left. The
   parameters I used were:

> Option 3: Distance Along Line: 250 ; Option 4: Distance of Station
>   Line: 50 ; Option 5: Sides of the Line: Left

2. For the second Station Line Dataset I used the following paramerters. I named it Lines_Right.

> Option 3: Distance Along Line: 125 ; Option 4: Distance of Station
>   Line: 50 ; Option 5: Sides of the Line: Right

The output will look something like this:

[image]

3. Now look at the Attribute table for Lines_Right and select all values in the `ET_Station` field where `mod( "ET_STATION",250)=0`. This will select all the lines falling at a unit divisible by 250m and will this remove the duplicates.
4. Merge the Left and Right lines together. Then run the ET GeoWizards tool "Convert Lines to Points". Found in the ET GeoWizards Menu "Covernt -> PolyLine to Point". Select the Merged lines as the input and select your output. Choose Vertices as the Conversion option and Remove Duplicate Points. If you have the ArcGIS Advanced License you could also run the "Feature Vertices to Points" Tool.
5. With this new output, run a selection by location for any points occuring on the original centreline and delete them. You will be left with the image shown at the beginning.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for the help @keagan Allan. I will try. Although I still be needing the code, but I believe once it is done, the code can be extracted.

Comment: If it answers your question, please dont forget to tick the correct answer to mark your question as answered and complete.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps,

1. Generate a buffer with 50m distance for the line feature.
2. Split at the curve of the buffer feature and delete both the curves from the buffer.
   [image]
3. Select buffer line/ Editor/ Construct points/ Select "Distance"- 50/ok. (50 is in meters by default)
   [image]
4. Points will be generated with 50m interval.

Note: For the second buffer line, in "Construct points", select the option- "From End point of line" to get the desired output.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I also want the distance between two points should be 250m.

Comment: In "Construct points"- give the distance 250. Points will be generated with 250m interval.